# application_responder (LoadError) Rails 6

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Getting `cannot load such file -- application_responder (LoadError)` with rails 6. I have commented this line in boot.rb `require 'bootsnap/setup'`.  Have also added this line in application.rb `config.autoload = :classic`. Still, no luck.

Any help ??

Answer (score 1):

Responders is a ruby gem that provides "A set of responders modules to dry up your Rails app". You have to follow it's installation guide: https://github.com/heartcombo/responders. Particularly, I think you are missing to run following command after bundle install:

```
rails g responders:install
```